# Using custom fonts in Xcode - Punctuation issue

Tags: iphone, fonts, xcode4.2, embedding

When I make an `NSString`, for instance: `@"Thanks, Lucy!"`
The comma would not come up but the exclamation point would.

Or if I use `NSDateFormatter`, something like `December 12, 2012` would just come up with spaces: `December 12  2012`.

Is there a line/method in Xcode to embed characters when using a local custom font like I am (`UIAppFonts`)?

Thanks!
Keith

Comment: Can you tell us more about this local custom font?

Comment: The Custom Font you are using does not have a comma character. So you are not going to be able to display a comma using that specific font.

Comment: ...Any thoughts? I really cant find anything on the subject of ensuring punctuation in Xcode using a custom font... Any information will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like WrightsCS said, your custom font does not include the character (comma) you need. You either need to find another font that works for you, or you need to edit the font you want to include the characters you need using a font editor like Fontographer. An experienced graphic designer could do that for you.

Also don't forget that most font licenses forbid embedding fonts into software without a special license from the font publisher.